# Jar file won't recognize mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, odbc

I made a swing application in Eclipse and it works and compiles fine in Eclipse. It's connecting to mysql. The problem is when I turned it into a jar file the database won't connect. When the application is supposed to load the information from the db, nothing is happening.

```
public boolean deleteAttendance(String idno,String eventtitle)
{
    int x;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "","");
        String query = "DELETE FROM attendance WHERE id =? AND title = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        pstmt.setString(1, idno);
        pstmt.setString(2, eventtitle);
        x = pstmt.executeUpdate();

        if(x != 0)
        return true;
        else
            return false;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Statement Error " + e);
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is happening"? What have you done to debug? Are you sure you're even getting in the method? Is an exception thrown? Can your jar find the database driver "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"?

Comment: Why oh why are you using the JDBC-ODBC driver instead of a native MySQL driver? The JDBC-ODBC driver has been released more than 10 years ago to compensate for the absence of JDBC drivers for some databases, because JDBC was brand new then. It should not be used anymore nowadays.

Comment: first i tried it running my double clicking the jar file but no database is displayed then i tried running it from a command prompt using this command java -jar app.jar and it works fine

Comment: @JBNizet i'll take note of it. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Just to check whether it is the problem with your required jars not on the class path

`Go to window -> preferences->java->build path->user Libraries.` add your jar to new user library. Now create a new java project in eclipse right click on this project and select add libraries and add the library your just added in your eclipse . Also add required libraries for database (if any) to your project. If on running your jar everything is working fine then surely its the problem of you not adding `ODBC/JDBC` driver to your class path else its a problem with your jar .

Comment: thx for the info, but it didnt work so im guessing its with the libraries for the database to my project not being included in the classpath?

Comment: oh i see, when i tried it on the command prompt it works fine. Just by typing java -jar app.jar. But what do i have to do to make it work just by double clicking on it?

Comment: When you double-click the jar, does the application start at all?

Comment: If you want to make it work on double click one option is to create a packaged jar that contains supporting jars also.

Comment: AH YEA, i'll take note of that. I've done that before. Hope it works! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make sure that the ODBC driver is in your classpath.

Eclipse does a good job of making sure that your driver is there (because you have to include your dependency jars or else get errors trying to use them).

But once you leave Eclipse - you have to do it yourself.

Is it in your classpath?

Comment: The JDBC/ODBC bridge is part of the JDK, there is nothing to "include" or to configure.

Comment: Ah - I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: how do i check the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, go to artifact and add ojdbc.jar and click OK.
If true then nothing, if not then re-create the jar file.
note:Just make sure ojdbc.jar is added.